# implementation of passing variables by reference

Tags: compiler-construction

I have to implement a way to parse functions with parameters passed by reference in YACC and LEX.
Exemple:

```
int main (){
int a = 5;
f(a);
printf(a)
return 0;
}

f(passed_by_reference int b){
b++;
}
```

I tryed to use symbol table but cannot match variable a and variable b because in the table they are saved like a and b, so changes are lost.

Any idea?

Comment: It seems to me that this is a semantic implementation question, which has nothing to do with syntax (what lex and yacc deal with) or parsing.

Answer (score 0):

As far as parsing is concerned, you just need to recognize the keyword `passed_by_reference`<sup>1</sup> as a modifier to a function parameter.

Then, in your semantics, when you bind the function call to the function definition, you bind the argument to the parameter by reference rather than by value.  How you do that depends entirely on how you're implementing your semantics.  Are you interpreting some IR or AST produced by your parser?  Or are you generating code of some kind for some target execution model?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> More commonly, you would use `inout` or `&`.</sub>

Comment: I have a parser code wit all working, and i'm asked to implement the possibility to pass variable by reference. I'm supposed to interpret C code. I tryed to duplicate the code that handle normal variable passing and change it in order to catch the `passed_by_reference` string and try to return a pointer to a value but... did not successed... I'm pretty confused

Comment: @bogALT: so in your interpreter code, bind the the argument to the parameter by reference instead of just copying the value.

Comment: i'll try, let you know

Comment: @Crhris Dodd: ot, that's the problem , I cannot bind the argument instead of passing it :( may I'm doing it wrong...